# How to get the space used by SQL Server back?

Tags: sql-server

I have created a table on SQL Server then inserted 135 million records in that table.

then I truncate it

then tried to re-insert the same 135 million records again.

but something went wrong and had to restart the computer

I got the recovery mode in my database.

then fixed.

the problem now is C drive has 10GB free only (210GB used) while before that I used to have 105GB free!

I checked folders but the sum of all sizes including hidden ones does not sum to 210GB

what happened and where did these GBs have gone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best solution: Buy a new drive ( like SSD 1TB)  :-D --- Other temporary solution :a.Detach and Attach DB in other space b.Check log file - data gona go to the log in the first step...then write in DB---clear data log: https://www.isunshare.com/sql-server/how-to-empty-and-delete-sql-server-log-file.html d.Compress data in your drive. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-ntfs-compression-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is not automatically released by the database. In the case of `tempdb`, if you restart the sql service, tempdb will reinitialize to original size. But, not the case for other databases.

If you want to reclaim the space, there are two approaches:

1. **Cleaner approch:**

As suggested by Paul Randal, go for new filegroup for existing tables and then drop the old filegroup.[Refer to his article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/)

> - Create a new filegroup
> - Move all affected tables and indexes into the new filegroup using the CREATE INDEX … WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON) ON syntax, to move the
>     tables and remove fragmentation from them at the same time
> - Drop the old filegroup that you were going to shrink anyway (or shrink it way down if its the primary filegroup)

2. **Brute Force approach and redmediation**

Here, you can use DBCC SHRINKFILE and reduce the size. Keep little more space in the database to avoid frequent autogrowth. Beware that, shrinking file will lead to index fragmentation and you have to rebuild indexes post the shrinking of files.

As Paul Randal recommends:

> If you absolutely have no choice and have to run a data file shrink
>   operation, be aware that you’re going to cause index fragmentation and
>   you might need to take steps to remove it afterwards if it’s going to
>   cause performance problems. The only way to remove index fragmentation
>   without causing data file growth again is to use DBCC INDEXDEFRAG or
>   ALTER INDEX … REORGANIZE. These commands only require a single 8KB
>   page of extra space, instead of needing to build a whole new index in
>   the case of an index rebuild operation (which will likely cause the
>   file to grow).